# Why won't for(true;true;std::cin>>str) work?

Tags: c++

I know I can input text from the console using `while (std::cin >> str)`.

When I try the following as an equivalent for loop, I get an unhelpful error in Visual C++ 2010. Why is this technically incorrect?

```
    for (true; true; std::cin>>str) 
    {
         // Get input forever 
    }
```

Comment: And the "useless error" is...?

Comment: this is not equivalent; And your comment '\\' is wrong. Use forward slashes.

Comment: @GManNickG Unhandled exception at 0x76c8b9bc in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0045f628..

Comment: That seems quite a bit of an useful 'error'

Comment: I'm not saying it does not have its purpose, but it is not doing much to show me what when wrong in my code.

Comment: that error doesn't seem to do with how you began your loop, but rather accessing memory you are not supposed to

Comment: how do you declare `str`? does it have any memory allocated at all?

Comment: The error message is telling you that you've made a mistake in memory management. It has little to do with the way you've written the for-loop.

Comment: If `str` is a char array, then `std::cin >> str` is an error in and of itself, no matter where it occurs.

Comment: -1 for "unhelpful error".  Just because you don't understand what it means doesn't mean someone else won't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing your error is something to the effect of using an uninitialized variable, `str`. The reason is because the last argument in the for loop doesn't execute until after the loop completes the first iteration.

Also, if you need an infinite loop you could do this or a number of other loop setups:

```
for ( ; ; ) {
    std::cin >> str;
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: It's probably not uninitialized, but merely empty.  And yes, that could break logic inside the loop body.

Comment: You're welcome! and I feel your pain. C++ error messages can be rather cryptic and often only describe what happened, not how it happened or from where it was caused.

Answer (score 6):

Equivalent would be

```
for(;std::cin>>str;) {}
```

Comment: @JasonSage because the second part of the for loop is the bool check, so if the stream fails then the for loop would end.

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent for loop should be

```
for (; std::cin >> str; ) {}
```

because the seconde statement in for loop tells when it should stop. When input ends, `std::cin >> str` returns EOF and stops the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a useful usage of for.  For is meant to iterate, not loop until a result occurs as while does.

for(;std::cin>>str;) {}

is what you are looking for (as posted above).  But, the real issue is why add the extra boilerplate code and risk of error instead of the while?

Also, I generally don't like assignment in my conditional testing (in the for or while) because unexpected consequences could do weird things.  While this case is probably fine, I prefer:

```
while(true) {
    cin >> str;

    if(....) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Upside: This is crystal clear and nothing but what you explicitly program can break the loop.

Downside: This takes more lines of code and has an infinite loop which might trip out an error in a code analysis tool.